# Create more mongodb concurrent connections

Tags: mongodb, configuration

We are using mongodb 3.4.5 version

I would like to use more concurrent connections. Available connection showing 8 lakhs but the connection establishing is 100 by 100. For example,if we create 20,000 connections via pymongo, it is creating 100 by 100 and reaching 20,000 instead of creating 20,000 connections immediately.

```
db.runCommand( { "connPoolStats" : 1 } )
```

returns:

```json
{
        "numClientConnections" : 0,
        "numAScopedConnections" : 0,
        "totalInUse" : 0,
        "totalAvailable" : 0,
        "totalCreated" : 0,
        "totalRefreshing" : 0,
        "pools" : {

        },
        "hosts" : {

        },
        "replicaSets" : {

        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

How to increase the limit it inside mongod or mongod.conf?

Total connections available and total pools available are different right?
I have total available connections 800k. I need to increase only pool size. I am using single node.

Comment: What version of PyMongo are you using, and what are your options for `MongoClient`? Also, why do you want to create 20,000 connections immediately rather than ramping up as needed? That seems a very large connection pool; it will also use ~20GB of RAM on your MongoDB server (up to 1MB per connection).

Answer (score 1):

Check your connection pool size information [with connPoolStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/connPoolStats/)

`db.runCommand( { "connPoolStats" : 1 } )`

From there you can see what is f.ex. max possible connection count. That depend how much your server have memory.

And with connection [string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) you can set max and min poolsize. 100 is default value.

About current connections, `db.serverStatus().connections` shows information.
For production systems it is typical to adjust the ulimit settings on Linux to allow more concurrent connections. For more best practices, I would recommend reviewing the [Production Notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/) in the MongoDB manual.

But you still need to change your `connectionPool` values before you can go over that 100 connections.

> net.maxIncomingConnections
> Type: integer
>
> Default: 65536
>
> The maximum number of simultaneous connections that mongos or mongod will accept. This setting has no effect if it is higher than your operating system’s configured maximum connection tracking threshold.

Total connections available tells how many connections that node can have. `connPoolStats.totalAvailable` tell how much that connection pool can have. You need to change your pool size.